# Mapping from uname -m to /usr/src/linux-headers/arch/*

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, arm, ebpf

I'm building an eBPF program. For it to build I need to add as include paths (`-I`) some headers located in `/usr/src/linux-headers-*/arch/x86/include`.

Since this path is x86-specific, to be able to compile it for non-x86 architectures I will need to pick the right path as part of the build process.

However, the names of the architectures used in the Linux sources don't match those returned by `uname -m`. Eg, if `uname -m` returns `x86_64` I need to include `arch/x86/include`, but if `uname -m` returns `aarch64`, then I need to include `arch/arm64/include`.

Is there a way to find which is the right `arch/*` to include, without the need to use a mapping (`uname -m` -> arch path) for all my supported architectures?

Comment: Since I'm new I can't tag this as ebpf (because it's not a popular tag), but it would be nice if someone can do it.

Comment: `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/source/Makefile` contains the mapping (and `.../build/Makefile` knows how to find it); that’s how out-of-tree kernel modules get the right includes. There might be a way of re-using that for eBPF builds...

Comment: Could you detail what headers you are looking for in `/usr/src/linux-headers-*/arch/x86/include/`?

Comment: @Qeole I'm including <linux/ptrace.h> and that ends up pulling from there.

Comment: Hmm I don't need to pass any `-I` flag when including `<linux/ptrace.h>` on my machine :/. Any chance you could provide a minimal example + command line you use to compile?

Comment: `linux/ptrace.h` includes `linux/sched.h` which includes `linux/cputime.h` which includes `asm/cputime.h` which is arch-specific. This is with kernel 4.9.